# Retrieve a value from MongoDB collection based on another identifier

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a mongo collection like below

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("63a03f729755062cbced5298"),
    bat: 30,
    ball: 45,
    version: 1
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("63a03f729755062cbced5299"),
    bat: 100,
    ball: 50,
    version: 2
  }
]
```

Now using PyMongo based on the "version", I want to extract the price of the "bat". Say for version 1, I am using the below query. Is the below query optimised? I want to avoid the list conversion and lookup using indexes, rather do it using Mongo query itself. Any idea?

```
price = list(collection.aggregate([{"$match": {"version": 1}}]))[0]["bat"]
```

Comment: if it's just one find_one?

Comment: collection.find_one({"version": 1}, {"bat": 1, "_id": 0}), tried this but it returns dictionary. Anyway to get the value alone using Mongo query itself?

Comment: getting an answer from a dictionary is fast. that's whats dictionaries are for. fast lookup. i don't think you can get a single value from a mongo query